# generate prediction with normal data from algorithm trained with organized data

Tags: python, xgboost, preprocessor

I trained a model with XGBRegressor and saved the model with pickle. Before training the model, I applied "LabelEncoder" and "MinMaxScaler" to my data, I want to receive data from the user and produce a response with this model, but can I make a prediction without applying the changes made by LabelEncoder and MinMaxScaler to the data?

Comment: No, you should apply the exact same `LabelEncoder` and the exact same ("trained" using train data, _not_ the new data!) `MinMaxScaler` to the new data and pass the result to the model.

Comment: do i have to retrain the algorithm every time i want to get results?

Comment: No, that's the entire point of saving the model: you train it, save it, then use it for inference however many times you need.

Comment: I need to add the new data to the dataset I trained and apply the LabelEncoder and MinMaxScaler, then I need to take it and make a prediction in the algorithm?

Comment: Is there a way to save the LabelEncoder and MinMaxScaler applied to the training data?

Comment: No, you should save three things: `LabelEncoder`, `MinMaxScaler` and your model, then transform the new data point using the encoder and the scaler and feed that to your model. No need to add anything to the training dataset. In fact, you don't need it anymore after training the model. I guess you could save everything using `pickle` or check whether xgboost and/or `sklearn` provide special facilities for saving encoders/scalers/models.

Comment: @ForceBru I saved my MinMaxScaler, but when I make the prediction I created "inverse_transform", I get a reshape(1, -1) error, but I cannot reshape because I produced 1 answer. what can i do as a solution?

Comment: That's a separate question. You could probably ask it in a separate post here. Please don't forget to provide a [mcve] and explain what exactly you mean by "a reshape(1, -1) error". Good luck!